# Workaround for an API not allowing require a specific library (luasocket) and not able to include it via moving DLL

Tags: go, redis, lua, luasocket

I am using an API called [Piepan](https://github.com/layeh/piepan), which allows me to write Lua scripts for Mumble bots. For context, it is written in Golang using an alternative mumble implementation called [Gumble](https://github.com/layeh/gumble/). Piepan scripts are executed via cmd prompt through a piepan.exe.
I can require most libraries, like [inspect.lua](https://github.com/kikito/inspect.lua), and I can easily require luasocket in non-piepan scripts (scripts executed via lua.exe), but if I try to require luasocket (or what I really want, a [redis library](https://github.com/nrk/redis-lua) that depends on luasocket), I get an error. This is less of an error and more of a missing feature from the API, which the creator [acknowledges](https://github.com/layeh/piepan/issues/37). The creator suggests to someone else with this problem that they simply use Gumble, but I cannot do that as I am only a Lua programmer.

Here's the code of me just trying to require luasocket:

```
local socket = require ("include-test.socket")
```

(I've also tried include-test.socket.core and just socket.core)

In accordance with this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47117239/how-to-require-lua-socket) answer, I moved my files to resemble the user's own directory, so it looks like this:

```
Piepan folder
-piepan exe and dlls (not luasocket dlls)
-include-test (folder)
--Script for piepan
--socket.lua
--socket folder
---core.dll
```

Despite the directory looking how I imagine it should based on other users' Q/As, I get this error:

```
.\include-test\socket.lua:13: module socket.core not found:
    no field package.preload['socket.core']
    Lstat : The system cannot find the path specified.
    GetFileAttributesEx .\socket\core.lua: The system cannot find the path specified.
    GetFileAttributesEx C:\Users\Michael\piepan\lua\socket\core.lua: The system cannot find the path specified.
    GetFileAttributesEx C:\Users\Michael\piepan\lua\socket\core\init.lua: The system cannot find the path specified.
    GetFileAttributesEx C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua\socket\core.luac: The system cannot find the path specified.,
```

I've also tried including the following line, inspired by this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244380/luasocket-socket-core-dll-required-location) answer.

```
package.cpath = package.cpath .. ';include-test/?.dll'
```

to no avail.

I am looking for any available solution, whether that be moving around dlls or compiling the original Piepan w/ extra files as needed. 
(To clarify, I need a workaround that allows me to require the redis library within the same script I run through piepan. Using an outside script with the redis library to then, say, launch piepan and do something there, is not helpful to me.)

Comment: Piepan uses GopherLua (Lua VM written in Go), and GopherLua is unable to load DLL Lua modules.  The most realistic workaround is to find some Go library (which works with redis) and modify Piepan (to expose this library to Lua scripts).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Okay, thank you for the clear diagnosis and prescription! I was like 40% certain the dll was irreconcilable with piepan but wanted to put out a question in case there was a solution.